# There is a null reference exception to merge two data table

Tags: merge, datatable, nullreferenceexception

I'm going to call data from the DAL, send it to the BLL, and I'll give it to XtraReport. The scenario is as follows:
In the DAL:

```cs
public static List<t_Products> GetAllProductList()
{
            try
            {
                return objContext.t_Products.OrderBy(c => c.f_ProName).ToList();
            }
......
}
```

in the BLL:

```
public static List<t_Products> GetAllProductList()
{
           return DAL.DALProducts.GetAllProductList();
       }
```

in the UI:

```
List<t_Products> ProductList = BLLProducts.GetAllProductList();
 var queryProduct=ProductList.Where(c => c.f_ProTypeID == 1)
                .Select(current=>new {current.f_ProductID,current.f_ProCode,current.f_P  roName,current.f_ProWeight,current.f_ProTypeID});
//create datatable from linq query
productDataTable =Utilities.IEnumerableToDataTable.LINQToDataTable(  queryProduct);

private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (productDT.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
//sending datatable to Xtrareport
                Reports.XtraReports.ProductsAndBOM x = new Reports.XtraReports.ProductsAndBOM(productDT);
                x.Report();
            }
            else
....        }
```

Finally, I put in a XtraReport named ProductAndBOM, I have a DataSet called mahshamDataSet, in which there is a data table called t_Product. I've put the fields in this table on the report.I put the DataTable sent to the report, using the Merge command in the t_Product data table:

```
public partial class ProductsAndBOM : DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport
    {
        public ProductsAndBOM()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        System.Data.DataTable requiredRawMaterilSource;
        System.Data.DataTable productsSource;
        public ProductsAndBOM(System.Data.DataTable products)
        {
            productsSource = products;
        }
        new public void Report()
        {
            mahshamDataSet1.t_Products.Merge(productsSource);
            ProductsAndBOM productBOMXtraReport = new ProductsAndBOM();
            ReportPrintTool printTool = new ReportPrintTool(productBOMXtraReport);
            UserLookAndFeel lookAndFeel = new UserLookAndFeel(this);
            lookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel = false;
            lookAndFeel.SkinName = "Office 2016 Colorful";
            printTool.ShowRibbonPreview(lookAndFeel);
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, when I merge the data table sent into the report with the mahshamDataSet1.t_Products table, I get the following error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Mahsham.UI.exe
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Thanks, friends. Check the codes. See what I should do to avoid this error, and 
is this process correct, you think?. Thankful

Answer (score 0):

I got my problems:

```
public partial class ProductsAndBOM : DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport
    {
        public ProductsAndBOM(System.Data.DataTable products)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            productsSource = products;
        }
        //System.Data.DataTable requiredRawMaterilSource;
        System.Data.DataTable productsSource;

        public ProductsAndBOM()
        {

        }

        new public void Report()
        {
            //mahshamDataSet1 = new Data.MahshamDataSet();

           // ProductsAndBOM productBOMXtraReport = new ProductsAndBOM();
            mahshamDataSet1.t_Products.Merge(productsSource);
            ReportPrintTool printTool = new ReportPrintTool(this);
            UserLookAndFeel lookAndFeel = new UserLookAndFeel(this);
            lookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel = false;
            lookAndFeel.SkinName = "Office 2016 Colorful";
            printTool.ShowRibbonPreview(lookAndFeel);
        }

    }
```

Before any initialization I tried to fill data table.  Thankful.